# Python splitting specific nmap output

Tags: python, regex

I have the following output from nmap and i am trying to split into the sections like nmap has it, like the following:

```
PORT | STATE | SERVICE | VERSION
```

The output would look like this:

```
2000/tcp  open  cisco-sccp?
3000/tcp  open  http           Apache httpd 2.2.3 ((CentOS))
```

I tried using the string.split() but it keeps giving me everything in its own entry, so ultimately what i am trying to get is the "Apache httpd 2.2.3 ((CentOS))" but i can't get that at all, it keeps putting every word in an entry. I even tried

```
re.split('\s+', string)
```

But that also yields the same result. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a general solution, but for this specific example, I think just specifying a `maxsplit` would work:

```
In [7]: re.split(r'\s+', '3000/tcp  open  http           Apache httpd 2.2.3 ((CentOS))', 3)
Out[7]: ['3000/tcp', 'open', 'http', 'Apache httpd 2.2.3 ((CentOS))']
```

That tells it to split 3 times, but then just leave the rest as-is.

Short lines just are shorter and don't have 4 items:

```
In [8]: re.split(r'\s+', '2000/tcp  open  cisco-sccp?', 3)
Out[8]: ['2000/tcp', 'open', 'cisco-sccp?']
```

Comment: perfect, exactly what i was looking for, didn't know about the maxsplit, thanks a lot, really appreciate it